# The bottom content of the scrollView is not not responding to touch events

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, subview

I have scroll view. In side scroll view I have a container view with trailing,leading,top and bottom constraints and also equal heights. I'm adding views dynamically. I'd updated the content size in

> viewWillLayoutSubviews as follows.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.contentView.frame.width, height: self.contentView.frame.height)
        self.contentView.frame = CGRect(x: self.contentView.frame.minX, y: self.contentView.frame.minY, width: self.contentView.frame.width, height: 2500) // code to update the contentView's frame where 2500 is a dummy value
        self.contentView.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```

Now I can scroll until my last subview of the container view. But the problem is the last 3 subviews are not responding to the touch events.

I tried the following ways but failed.

- also updated the containterView's frame
- also updated the    scrollview's frame

did not work.
Please help me.

Comment: Check your bottom 3 view's frame with container view.

Comment: last 3 subviews are not responding to the touch events -> make sure isUserInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: isUserInteractionEnabled = true .It is enabled. I've cross checked it.@NhatDinh

Comment: Problem is with your contentView height, I agree that your scrollview scrolls to bottom, you can see subviews at bottom still this problem occurs due to contentView height. Try to set hard coded height constraint to contentView of your UIScrollView.

Comment: I'd put a breakpoint in the viewWillLayoutSubview and checked the frame. It is showing (0,0,0,0) but it is visible in the simulator. @RahulPatel

Comment: I'd tried that also @Tejas . still not able to interact with them

Comment: @RamcharanReddy Not like this, try it in Debug View Hierarchy
may be your container view's clipsToBounds property value is false, if i am right, please set it to true and check.

Comment: @RamcharanReddy Ok. I have faced this problem one's, I solved this using hard-coded height constraint to contentView, Have you removed code which sets contentSize in method viewWillLayoutSubviews ?. 

Also try scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false.

Comment: @RahulPatel,i've made it true. The part which was not responding has gone. It's not appearing now.

Comment: This is done, because your last 3 views having frames, which is not containing by container view.

because clipsToBounds = false, your container view shows its subview which are not fall within container view's hight.

please update frame of container view's frame, and you can see your last 3 views also, and they can be touched.

Comment: @RahulPatel, I have added hard coded (ex: 2000) as contentView's height. But still there is no change. they are not appearing. Can you please provide me this idea as an answer ?

Comment: put your code in question for updating view container's frame, i ll try to explain in answer, if i can

Comment: Now please check it and help me in resolving @RahulPatel

Comment: if you are using contentView, inside scrollView , try to make the size of it equal to scroll content height or remove it and add your views directly to UIScrollview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 func updateFrame() {
            self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.contentView.frame.width, height: self.contentView.frame.height)
    self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.contentView.frame = CGRect(x: self.contentView.frame.minX, y: self.contentView.frame.minY, width: self.contentView.frame.width, height: 2500) // code to update the contentView's frame where 2500 is a dummy value
            self.contentView.clipsToBounds = true
        }
```

try this.
I am assuming that your scrollview is bigger then Content view

Comment: instead of viewWillLayoutSubviews, call this method updateFrame manually

Comment: check contentView's frame using Debug View Hierarchy
is that actually updating or not?

Comment: there is nothing in it. but i have added them in viewDidLoad()

Comment: buddy, never set frame in view did load, it will not affected, or call it with dispatchasynch main queue if you want to update frame in viewdid load.

Do you know Debug View Hierarchy?

Comment: what i'm saying is i have added subviews in viewDidLoad(), but when i check debug view hierarchy in debug area, there is nothing showing @Rahul Patel, also please tell me how to use debug hierarchy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134957/discussion-between-rahul-patel-and-ramcharan-reddy).